# How do I check the download progress of Mountain Lion through the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am downloading Mountain Lion, I know I can monitor download progress through the Mac App Store purchases screen but I want to know if I can monitor progress through Terminal.app using a shell command.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question but is it not much easier to just click on the Purchases "tab" in App Store and watch the progress bar?

Comment: I know you can do it in the Purchases tab.  I wanted to know if it could be done in the Terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided that the best way to identify the file being downloaded was to write a small script that fetched the files held open by the App Store program `storeagen`.

```
#!/bin/bash
appstore_pid=$(ps -ef|grep storeagen|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}')
lsof -p $appstore_pid|grep private|awk '{print $7 "\t" $9}'
```

I set `appstore_pid` variable to the PID of `storeagen` by extracting it from the `ps` command using `grep` and `awk`

Then I use `lsof` to list open files by the PID of `storeagen` and I print out the size of the files and the files path.  If you do this several times in succession you can see the file(s) that's growing and make a good guess by its size that it is the OS download.

Comment: Nice use of lsof ;-) I piped to a second `grep` for pkg since I've seen the `lsof` return four or more items in /private/var/...

Answer (score 8):

Sure - the storeagent uses a folder deep within /private/var/folders to hold the download progress.

On my Mac it's downloading to this folder below - yours may change, but you should be able to search for the com.apple.appstore using `mdfind` and use `du` or `ls` to see the file size grow.

```
/private/var/folders/tv/xyw2rpln7hq4gw2m0prg_src0000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/497799835
```

The App Store has a nicer wrapper on the progress with a time estimate, but with `bc` and other tools, you could do the same in a short shell script exercise.

---

If you can't locate your folder, this `find` command might be of use to narrow down your search....

```
sudo find /var/folders -type d -name com.apple.appstore -print
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain how to find the right directory?

Comment: Sure - I just did a brute force search based on last modified time and ls - but I'll edit in a `find` command that worked for me...

Comment: `du -h /private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.appstore/*/*.pkg` would print the size of the download in a human-readable format. The total size of the version I'm currently downloading is shown as 4.3 GB in App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the activity monitor and watched how much data transfer was happening...
And ensure no other traffic at the time of download. Its not perfect, but gives you a general idea something is happening.